# How to simulate a Stewart Platform with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to simulate a Stewart Platform with  ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244903/how-to-simulate-a-stewart-platform-with-ros?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**update**

I've made a ros node https://github.com/lucasw/simple_sim_ros that is a light wrapper around the bullet physics simulator, and it can create a stewart platform:

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

It is lacking important features like closed loop actuator control, currently it can only take impulses rather than actuator extension commands, but I'll add that later.

**Old answer**

Also http://answers.ros.org/question/216101/stewart-platform-how-can-i-connect-multiple-joints-to-the-same-child-link-but-different-parent-links/ and http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3696/how-to-simulate-a-stewart-platform-with-gazebo-and-ros/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart_platform looks like the platform would involve a tf frame with six parents, but multiple parents aren't allowed in urdf.

Perhaps it is allowed in Gazebo with SDF?  In that case you would need to have gazebo-only code/scripts/launch files that launches the platform, then some bridging code that gets transform info from gazebo and publishes it into ros.  This could evolve involve a ros-gazebo plugin later, and within urdf the user would specify the general parameters of the platform.

You could do something with Gazebo very hacky and cpu intensive and possibly unstable simulation-wise involving a platform that isn't actually parented to the actuators but is physically constrained by mostly interlocking collision objects.

You could make or perhaps find some off the shelf stewart platform code that solves forward kinematics for the orientation of the platform and the actuators given how much the actuators are extended and run it in a ros node, and that would publish those transforms for the actuators and the platform. (And you already need inverse kinematics solved to make the system useful, though perhaps you were hoping the forward kinematics from a generic simulation would validate your special case inverse kinematics...)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-10-15**:
thanks a lot . but when i run this command: roslaunch bullet_server bullet_server.launch

i have this error : ERROR: cannot launch node of type [bullet_server/bullet_server]: can't locate node [bullet_server] in package [bullet_server]

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-10-16**:
`git clone https://github.com/lucasw/simple_sim_ros.git` into your `catkin_ws/src` and build it first.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-10-16**:
thanks a lot .
but when i run  this command:
roslaunch bullet_server bullet_server.launch

i have empty space .

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-10-17**:
That's just the server, `rosrun bullet_server stewart_platform.py` in another terminal will create the stewart platform.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-10-17**:
thanks a lot

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-10-17**:
how can i controlling this platform ?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-10-17**:
You'll have to git pull to the latest, there are currently only Float32 velocity control topics for the six actuators, publish to `/prismatic_0/target_lin_motor_vel` and subscribe to `/prismatic_0/linear_pos` to get position feedback, you'd have to write your own position controller...

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-10-17**:
...but I'll probably have one working in a few days.  There is also a bug where the simulation self-deactivates I should have fixed soon.  (using the add_impulse interface ought to re-activate it though)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-10-20**:
I've updated it so that the platform re-activates properly, and also each actuator has a setpoint command to set the desired position (you need the ros pid package installed, like ros-kinetic-pid).   Also `roslaunch bullet_server stewart_platform.launch` instead of rosrun stewart_platform.py

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2016-11-16**:
hi ! thanks a lot .
i saw this video :
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URoyLptHvCU)

thats amazing !  i want to show rqt plot like video . but i Dont know what to do . plese helpe me . can you
explain ?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-11-17**:
After stewart_platform.launch is running run rqt_plot and add `/prismatic_0/linear_pos/data`,  `/prismatic_1/linear_pos/data`,  `/prismatic_2/linear_pos/data` and so on to the Topic text entry box and press the plus sign for each one.

**Comment by [daniel-s-ingram](https://answers.ros.org/users/32965/daniel-s-ingram/) on 2017-12-22**:
Here's a link that implements your original suggestion to do it with an SDF, lucasw. All it took was a plugin to expose the Gazebo joints to ROS.

https://github.com/daniel-s-ingram/stewart_ros